# MacOs says external ssd disk is not readable, unable to repair it

Tags: macos, ssd

Im connecting a PNY CS900 SSD to my MacOs Catalina via USB. When I first plug it in I get an error message saying "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer."
[not readable error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OerHH.png)

I continue by pressing `Initialise..` and open `disk utility`. I dont care about whats on the ssd  I just want to be able to read/write to it so I do `erase` , I've tried both `ExFAT` and `MacOS Extended` with `guide partition map` , both scenarios gives the same result, "Couldn’t open device. : (-69877)". It then disappears from disk utilities.
[erase error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnyAY.png)

I run `First Aid` many times in before/after trying different kinds of `erase` and it always succeeds with "Operation successful."
[First Aid success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz3f4.png)

I also try to write an image from the disk, since I have Catalina I have fixed the security permissions in system preferences and allowed disk utility for full disk access, but still this results in error "Operation failed with status 16: Resource busy"
[image write error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtvd9.png)

I have no idea to proceed and would greatly appreciate some help, again I don't care about the contents of the ssd i just want to be able to use it.

Comment: Try a different SATA adaptor, try another computer.

Comment: The ssd to usb cable is brand new, for my mac i need an usb a to usb c adapter. I tried on an older mac with usb a and connected it directly, it didn't work there either, same results.

Comment: It may be new, but unless you eliminate it as the culprit, you're throwing the drive away without fully checking. I do suspect it's dead, but it could just be the cable.

Comment: So u are saying that either its the cable or theres nothing i can do?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error when plugging a BitLocker encrypted drive into my Mac. If this was the case, you should turn off the encryption first on a Windows device or third-party apps on Mac.

Also make sure the drive is not formatted by NTFS, which is not supported by Mac natively.